# Javascript URL Query String Logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, logic, query-string

I have an events listing page which can be filtered by type and also by date using query string variables.

I am trying to achieve the following logic using javascript/jQuery.

*I have a calendar which fires a function when updated. When fired I need to implement the following logic:*

- If the current URL contains `?filter=` then add `&dateStart=` to the end of the URL.
- If the current URL contains `?filter=` AND `&dateStart=` then keep the current filter value but replace the date query string with a new one.
- If the current URL contains ONLY `?dateStart=` then replace it with the new one.

I have tried various methods to achieve this but I keep hitting the problem of appending information to the end of the URL rather than replacing parts of it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: please post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

NOTE: not tested.

```
var newDateValue;
var myPath = window.location.pathname

//check if path contains the different variables
var containsFilter = myPath.indexOf("?filter=") != -1 ? true : false;
var containsAppendedDateStart = myPath.indexOf("&dateStart=" != -1 ? true : false;
var containsDateStart = myPath.indexOf("?dateStart=" != -1 ? true : false;

if(containsFilter && !containsAppendedDateStart){

   // If the current URL contains ?filter= then add &dateStart= to the end of the URL.
   window.location.replace(window.location.href + "&dateStart=");
}else if(containsFilter && containsAppendedDateStart){

   //If the current URL contains ?filter= AND &dateStart= then keep the current filter value but replace the date query string with a new one.
   newDateValue = 10; // add your new value here
   var splittedPathArray = myPath.split("&dateStart=");
   var newUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + splittedPathArray[0] + "&dateStart=" + addNewValue;
   window.location.replace(newUrl);

}else if(containsDateStart){
   // If the current URL contains ONLY ?dateStart= then replace it with the new one.
   newDateValue = 15;// add your new value here
   var splittedPathArray =  myPath.split("?dateStart=");
   var newUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + splittedPathArray[0] + "?dateStart=" + addNewValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this more easy with native **Web API** or **vanilla javascript** than with jQuery. As far as jQuery don't provide any specific function to work with query strings.

The new **URLSearchParams** object provide a few methods to work more easily with URL query strings. In your case for example you'll need to do something like this:

```
function updateQueryString(queryString, dateStart) {
  var queryString = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
  queryString.has('dateStart')
    ? queryString.set('dateStart', dateStart)
    : queryString.append('dateStart', dateStart);
  return queryString.toString();
}
```

#### for this solution you'll need a polyfill

Sadly this is not yet implemented by the majority of web browsers and you'll need to *"polyfill"* the **URLSearchParams** object for this solution to work properly. You'll have to add this line to the `<head>` section in your html:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/v0.1.14/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

You can find more information about the [URLSearchParams in the Mozilla Developers Network Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams), the [WHATWG specification for the URL Standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/) or the [specification by the W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/url/)

## solution without polyfill

​
If you don't like to use *edge* features you still can do it without any extra polyfill. It would look like this:

```
function updateQueryString(queryString, dateStart) {
  var qsObject = {};
  queryString
    .substring(1) // ignore '?'
    .split('&').forEach(function (param) {
      param = param.split('=');
      qsObject[param[0]] = param[1];
    });
  qsObject['dateStart'] = dateStart;
  return '&' + Object.keys(qsObject)
    .map(function (key) {
      return key + '=' + qsObject[key];
    })
    .join('?');
}
```

Call whatever version of the `updateQueryString` function you rather like this:

```
updateQueryString(windonw.location.search, dateStart)
```